# The code seems correct but my files aren't getting deleted

Tags: python-3.x, windows

I heard that python can make life easier, I wanted to remove duplicates in folderA by comparing folderB with folderA, so I decided to download python and try coding with python. My code seems correct, however, my files are failing to delete, what's wrong with it?

I tried unlink but doesn't work.

```
import os

with open(r"C:\pathto\output.txt", "w") as a:
    for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\pathto\directoryb'):
       for filename in files:
         #f = os.path.join(path, filename)
         #a.write(str(f) + os.linesep) 
         a.write(str(filename) + '\n')

textFile = open(r'C:\output.txt', 'r')

line = textFile.readline()
while line:
 target = str(line)
 todelete = 'C:\directorya' + target
 if (os.path.exists(todelete)):
  os.remove(todelete)
 else:
  print("failed")
 line = textFile.readline()

textFile.close()
```

I want my files deleted, basically folderA contains some files in folderB, and I'm trying to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the place where you're deleting the file isn't actually deleting a file - it's deleting a variable that contains the file's information.

```
 todelete = 'C:\directorya' + target
 if (os.path.exists(todelete)):
  os.remove(todelete) # this is deleting todelete, but doesn't get rid of the file!
```

I had a similar problem in a program I've started on but with a list, and in the end I had to use this kind of format:

```
lst.remove(lst[val1][val2][val3]) # as opposed to something cleaner-looking, like 'lst.remove(var_to_del)'
```

It's a pain, but I hope that clarifies the issue! You'll have to go to the file without giving it a variable name.

Comment: `os.remove` and `list.remove` are completely unrelated. `os.remove(file)` effectively **deletes the file from disk**. `list.remove('value') removes the first item of the list whose value is 'value'. So, this answer is wrong.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you make a valid point, os.remove and list.remove are different. However, I'm not trying to provide a solution - my aim is to show by the example that deleting a variable doesn't actually have an effect when trying to remove data. If that's wrong would you care to explain? Thank you.